# Groovy install on Unix OS

Tags: unix, groovy

I want to install groovy on a unix server and test functionality.  I used manual instructions from the following link:

https://itekblog.com/centos-groovy-installation-tutorial-newbs-centos-6-x/

I think the java jdk is installed, but im not certain since I didnt do it myself.  I base my opinion on the following commands(i edited output with xxxs to obfuscate info):

```
[root@xxx groovy]# which java
/opt/xxx/xxx/bin/java
```

and

```
[root@xxx bin]# ll
total 48
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        29 Aug 10  2017 jar -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        30 Aug 10  2017 java -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        29 Aug 10  2017 jps -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/jps
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        32 Aug 10  2017 jstack -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/jstack
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        31 Aug 10  2017 jstat -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/jstat
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root jdk8        33 Aug 10  2017 keytool -> 
/opt/xxx/jdk8/current/bin/keytool
```

Here is my bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/groovy/groovy-2.5.1
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$GROOVY_HOME/bin

export PATH
```

I "reloaded" my profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Here is what happens when I try to "run" groovy:

```
[root@lhost-cl2 groovy]# groovy -e 'println("Hello, World!")'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What version of groovy have you installed? And what version of Java? `java -version`

Comment: [root@xxx bin]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
[root@xxx bin]# groovy -version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter (unrecognized class file version)  SHOULD RETURN GROOVY 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

There were two versions of java installed on the server.  The older version, not compatible with groovy, was being referenced.  I updated the path and its happy now.